# Dot matrix background

Tags: css

I want to have background HTML page with full of dot matrix like designing tool?

How can I do it?

If i should used background-image for this purpose where can I download the picture?

Thanks All.

Answer (score 1):

Make the image yourself then put it as a background-image on your page, as simple as that.

```
body {background-image:url(dotmatrix.png);}
```